# Diophantine equation: $3a^2+3b^2+19ab=0$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, diophantine-equations

Can this equation be solved in integers $a,b$ (Apart from $a=b=0$)? :

$3a^2+3b^2+19ab=0$

Thanks!

Comment: I think that the answer is no because $b=\frac{\pm5\sqrt{13}a-19a}{6}$, hence $a\in\mathbb{Z} \implies b\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ (in other words, for any integer value of $a$ you will get an irrational value of $b$). That is, with the exception of $a=0$.

Comment: For a number-theorist, this would be the most evil proof ever :P

Comment: @MooS: Haha ikr

Answer (score 2):

Let $(a,b)$ be a minimal nontrivial solution. Show that both $a$ and $b$ are even.

Then we get another solution $\left(\frac{a}{2},\frac{b}{2}\right)$, contradiction.

Comment: For $k$ even the same proof works and shows that it is not possible. For $k$ odd a similiar proof should work with reducing $\mod 3$ instead of $2$. Didn't come up with details yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve the equation for $b$ as a variable (and $a$ as a constant):

- $b_{1,2}=\dfrac{-19a\pm5\sqrt{13}a}{6}=\dfrac{-19\pm5\sqrt{13}}{6}a$
- $\forall{a\in\mathbb{Z}}:a\neq0\implies{b\not\in\mathbb{Q}}\implies{b\not\in\mathbb{Z}}$

In other words, for any integer value of $a\neq0$, you get an irrational value of $b$.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. Short and sweet, I didn't think of doing it like this.

Comment: @user45220: You're welcome :)